# loop through 10 days and store each date in an array

Tags: php, strtotime

I need to loop through dates to get the block of 1 days each. So that way I need total of 10 days. I tried this code, but that isn't working.

```
for($i=0; $i<=10;$i++)
     {
         $dates=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($current_date, "+1 days"));
         $tmp_array[$i]=$dates;
         debug($date);
     }
```

I get this error that prints infinite times.

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /Path/to/the/file on line 45
2014-12-03
```

Comment: Please post a completely working source snippet. Your current code snippet cannot reproduce the error as it's missing `$current_date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=0; $i<=10;$i++)
     {
         $temp = strtotime("+$i day");
         $dates=date("Y-m-d", $temp );
         $tmp_array[$i]=$dates;

     }
     print_r($tmp_array);
```

//output

```
Array ( [0] => 2014-12-03 [1] => 2014-12-04 [2] => 2014-12-05 [3] => 2014-12-06 [4] => 2014-12-07 [5] => 2014-12-08 [6] => 2014-12-09 [7] => 2014-12-10 [8] => 2014-12-11 [9] => 2014-12-12 [10] => 2014-12-13 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
    $dates[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "+$i days"));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($dates);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-12-03
    [1] => 2014-12-04
    [2] => 2014-12-05
    [3] => 2014-12-06
    [4] => 2014-12-07
    [5] => 2014-12-08
    [6] => 2014-12-09
    [7] => 2014-12-10
    [8] => 2014-12-11
    [9] => 2014-12-12
    [10] => 2014-12-13
)
```